# Visual C++ XDCMake is not executed

Tags: xml, documentation

Trying to make use of the XML documentation building C++ console app. XDC files are generated but the final XML is not. Looking at the diagnostic level of build log I find the following:

It seems the XDCMake is supposed to be assigned with list of all of the xdc files generated, but it is empty and hence the build bails. Question is why is that way on a freshly created project and freshly installed VC++ 2019?

```
15:59:27.406     1>Target "ResolvedXDCMake: (TargetId:89)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj" (target "_XdcMake" depends on it):
                   Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Extension)' == '.vcxproj' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '' and '$(_ClCompileGenerateXMLDocumentationFiles)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == '.vcxproj' and '' != '' and '' != '' and '' == 'true').
15:59:27.406     1>Done building target "ResolvedXDCMake" in project "ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj".: (TargetId:89)
15:59:27.406     1>Target "ComputeCLCompileGeneratedXDCFiles: (TargetId:90)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj" (target "_XdcMake" depends on it):
                   Added Item(s): 
                       XdcMake=
                           temp
                                   AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
                                   DocumentLibraryDependencies=false
                                   Local=true
                                   MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
                                   OutputFile=C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\x64\Debug\ChipEngineServerEmu.xml
                                   SuppressStartupBanner=true
                                   TrackerLogDirectory=x64\Debug\ChipEngi.eeecda29.tlog\
                   Set Property: XdcMakeAdditionalDocumentFile=
                   Removed Item(s): 
                       XdcMake=
                           temp
                                   AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
                                   DocumentLibraryDependencies=false
                                   Local=true
                                   MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
                                   OutputFile=C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\x64\Debug\ChipEngineServerEmu.xml
                                   SuppressStartupBanner=true
                                   TrackerLogDirectory=x64\Debug\ChipEngi.eeecda29.tlog\
15:59:27.406     1>Done building target "ComputeCLCompileGeneratedXDCFiles" in project "ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj".: (TargetId:90)
15:59:27.406     1>Target "MakeDirsForXdcMake: (TargetId:91)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj" (target "_XdcMake" depends on it):
                   Task "MakeDir" (TaskId:38)
                   Done executing task "MakeDir". (TaskId:38)
15:59:27.406     1>Done building target "MakeDirsForXdcMake" in project "ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj".: (TargetId:91)
                   Target "XdcMake" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(XdcMake)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
15:59:27.406     1>Target "_XdcMake: (TargetId:92)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Work\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu\ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj" (target "_BuildLinkAction" depends on it):
15:59:27.406     1>Done building target "_XdcMake" in project "ChipEngineServerEmu.vcxproj".: (TargetId:92)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/57C91630-95D6-4E3E-AF24-3415CC569AC8.htm

Following instructions on this page solved the problem...

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.